# How to make several Buttons and TextView as one section to scroll in android?

Tags: android, scroll

I want to have like a section which includes several buttons and TextView and this section is scrollable if texts in buttons or textview are too long to fit the section.

What am I looking for? ScrollView? How do I include these thing in a ScrollView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need scrollview.

in the scrollview there is a linearlayout and there you put your textview and buttons.

Comment: Is there any way I could use RelativeLayout in scrollview

Comment: just put a relative and not a linear layout